# What proportion of the variance of $\mathbf{X}$ is explained by the first PC and by the first two PC?

Tags: variance, pca

Suppose $\mathbf{X}$ takes values in $\mathbb{R}^p$ and has covaraince matrix:

$$\begin{bmatrix}
    14      & -10 & 10 & -2  \\
    -10      & 11 & -2 & -5  \\
    10      & -2 & 14 & -10 \\
     -2 & -5 & -10 & 11 \\
\end{bmatrix}$$

Now, I have found the PC scores for it:

$Y_1=\frac{5}{3}X_1-\frac{4}{3}X_2+X_3$

$Y_2=\frac{4}{3}X_1+\frac{5}{5}X_3+X_4$

$Y_3=\frac{1}{2}X_1-X_2-\frac{1}{2}X_3+X_4$

$Y_4=-2X_1+X_2-2X_3+X_4$

My question is:

What proportion of the variance of $\mathbf{X}$ is explained by the first PC **and** by the first two PC?

Comment: First compute the variances of the $Y_i.$  That will help you determine which are the first two PCs and it will indicate there there may be typographical errors.

Comment: @whuber but the first principal component is $Y_1$ and the second PC is $Y_2$ Why would there be typographical errors?

Comment: I can't explain why there are typographical errors--but there are.  You have the components backwards: $Y_4$ is the first PC, for instance.

Comment: Hmm, I find that the covariance matrix of ***X*** has rank 2. So the first two PC should explain the full variance (because there cannot be more than 2 PC's). What's wrong?